# Properties of a cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we know that $F_X(x)=P(X\le x)=x$.
So, if we were to look for $P(X\le x/n)$, can we say that $P(X\le x/n)=\frac{1}{n} P(X\le x)=\frac{1}{n}F_X(x)=\frac{x}{n}$ given $n$ is some constant

Comment: You cannot have $F_X(x)=x$ for all real $x$. Edit the question to make it more precise.

Comment: If $F_X(x)=P(X\le x)=x$ when $0 \le x \le 1$ then for $n\ge 1$ it follows immediately that $P(X\le x/n)=\frac{x}{n}$  when $0 \le x \le n$ since $0 \le \frac x n \le 1$

Answer (score 0):

No you can't factor out the $\frac1n$ in the CDF, the pdf although of the RV $Y=nX$ has a density of $f_Y(y)=\frac d{dy}F_X(y/n)=\frac1n f_X(y/n)$.